# Getting data from url hash in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url, hash

I am trying to read the "source" parameter and the "group" parameter from the url hash below.  I have no idea how to use regex and keep ending up with blank variables.

How do I read "source" and "group" parameters from the url hash below

```
    console.log(urlObj.hash); // #source-items?source=1002&?group=Menu
    var source = urlObj.hash.replace( /.*source=/, "");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `?` after `&` and you can use something like this:

```
function parseParams() {
    var params = window.location.hash.split('?')[1].split('&').map(function(item) {
        return item.split('=');
    });
    var namedparams = {};

    for (i=-1; param = params[++i]; ) {
        namedparams[param[0]] = param[1];
    }

    return namedparams;
}
```

This is how you use this function:

```
var params = parseParams();
params.group; // the group parameter
params.source; // the source parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function getParameterByName(urlString, name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(urlString);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

And invoke this by `getParameterByName(urlObj.hash, "source");`

**Update** : This is slightly modified version of the answer to [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/30594)